# Scanning 2D barcodes in java with zxing

Tags: java, zxing

I'm trying to scan 2D barcodes in Java with the following code:

```
InputStream in = null;
        BufferedImage bfi = null;
        File[] files = new File("codes").listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                bfi = ImageIO.read(in);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (bfi != null) {
                LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                        bfi);
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                        source));
                Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
                Result result = null;

                Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
                decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

                try {
                    result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ChecksumException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Text: " + result.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Buffered Image for"
                        + files[i].getName());
            }

        }
```

The types of images I'm trying to scan resemble this one:
http://www.apparategemeinschaft.de/07_s01.jpg

I would need to scan pdf417 predominantly.

It works when I simply scan a picture of a 2d-barcode. Is zxing even meant to be used for what Im trying to do?

I should make clear: for all .tif-images I scan, I get the message "no buffered image for ..."

UPDATE:

I added the following jars to the classpath: 
jai_imageio_linux-amd64.jar

And didnt change any code, as suggested by Robby.

It still doesnt work.

SECOND UPDATE:

I've got it now. The ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes() now includes .tiff as well.

New question: Do I have to tell zxing that there are more than one barcodes on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, by default, read a TIFF file into a buffered image using [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). Calling `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()` will return an array of the supported file formats which should at least include JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP and GIF.

You could use the [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html) which supports the TIFF format. Just adding the `JAI` jars to your classpath should be sufficient to make your code work.

You can find JAI downloads for your OS [here](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question has anything to do with barcodes or zxing. Your problem is that `ImageIO.read` returns `null`, right? It's not clear from your question.

Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)

The image is not readable to Java.

Comment: yes, that's most probably it, given Robby's comment. I wasn't a 100% sure, but looks like thats it. Thanx!